# Stop SuperDrive from checking for disks after wake up

Tags: audio, optical-drive

I'd like to stop the SuperDrive from spinning up after coming out of sleep since the noise it makes is quite loud. The SuperDrive was 'fixed' at an authorized retailer a while back and it's made a lot of noise ever since. This is a 3 year old white MacBook, so it's out of warranty.

Is there a way to not have it check for disks after opening the lid?

Comment: Is there a disk actually in the drive? Have you run the latest software updates? A while back there was a firmware update (I don't remember for which MacBooks though) that helped the 'noise' a superdrive makes when waking up.

Comment: @jmlumpkin Everything's up to date and there's no disk in the drive. It makes the same sound when it boots and when it wakes up; the sound is quite loud.

Comment: I had a unibody alum MacBook for a bit (they sold them for a few months, it looks just like the current 13" MBP). It had a very similar problem that was very annoying. There was a firmware upgrade for it that did quiet it down some, but it still was annoying.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the Superdrive if you set your account up under parental controls.

Under Preferences > Accounts (Users under Lion) > Enable parental controls > other > check limit cd and dvd burning

This should do the trick.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. The SuperDrive does the same thing after waking from sleep.